# Kitchen sink modelling

Tags: modeling

I am planning of a renovation, specifically my kitchen and I thought in doing it in Blender and UE4 since that would be a great opportunity to learn the programs as well.

I have managed to model the house (walls, windows, cabinets etc) and now I am in the process of modelling the appliances and stuff. I managed to do a fridge and now I am trying to model the kitchen sink in the photo:

[image]
I began with a simple plane and I managed to do the two bowls of the sink, but soon I ran into a problem because I noticed that this sink has three layers/planes or at least that's what I think.

So my question is this: Should I try and create more loop cuts in the specific plane and try to extrude/move/delete etc the edges or vertices? Or should I create the three layers separately in planes and join them together afterwards?

If I create those three planes, how could I "bend" the edges of my plane so I could get the shape of e.g. the second plane?

Is there perhaps an easier approach in this? Or a resource (e.g. article or tutorial) explaining something similar?

Please don't get me wrong I merely ask for a suggestion, not for someone to write a tutorial! :)

Thank you in advance and please excuse my English, it's not my native language!

Comment: Watch this timelapse "Modeling a kitchen sink" it might be helpfull https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLe4GAMmakQ

Comment: Wow! That sure opened up my eyes! :) Thank you so much!
It is way more difficult than I anticipated, but now at least I have a good understanding of what needs to be done!

Comment: use your photo as a background, follow the shapes and make several extrusions

Comment: I have placed the photo as a background but I can't seem to design the curves as I want them to be. In the second plane for example, I have to draw the curves but I can't seem to be able to do it. I have tried with bevel, adding a second plane within a plane, but nothing

Answer (score 2):

First use the picture as a background, draw all the lines, use shift ctrl B on vertices to create round corners, then join the vertices to fill the whole shape, then you can begin to extrude down. Afterwards, create some bevel to sharp the edges before you put a *Subsurf*.

[image]

Comment: Grrrreat!!! Seems like an easy and straight-forward way to do it. I will try it out tonight. Thank you sooo much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

for each of your layers, make an extrusion and play with the geometry a bit with the sub-surface modifier.  With the subsurf modifier applied, you will add alot less vertices with smoother curves when you add in loop cuts.

After you have the sink, use a boolean to cut its shape out of the counter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it tonight and let you know of my progress! :)
I hope that with the sub-surf modifier, I will be able to create those curves of the second plane